# Retrieving facebook user access token with socialite on laravel 5.4

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite

I am trying to get user access token so I can send CURL request through Guzzle to Facebook's Graph API to get user's friends that are using the app. But I can't seem to be able to obtain it.
Here's my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Socialite;

class SocialFriendsController extends Controller
{

    public function getFacebookFriends()
    {

    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    $access_token = $user->token;

    $client = new Client();
    $body = $client->get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/friends', [
        'query' => [
            'access_token' => '$access_token',
        ]
    ])->getBody();

        $result = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($body, 1);
    return view('pages.admin.posts.create', ['result' => $result]);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to note. First of all, the following part of your code won't work the way you expect it to:

```
'access_token' => '$access_token',
```

You're trying to do variable interpolation, which doesn't work when you use single quotes (`'`). You should use double quotes (`"$access_token"`) instead, or since you're not actually doing anything else with that string, you could just remove the quotes altogether.

Secondly, when doing Facebook logins (In your case, using Socialite) the access token you receive from Facebook is single use (I think so anyway - at least from my own experience). When you do `Socialite::driver('facebook')->user()`, Socialite is actually using the access token to grab the user object. If you attempt to use it again, Facebook will return an error.

Socialite is probably not the way to go to achieve what you're trying to do. I would suggest using the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) directly to get what you're after.

Comment: I was trying to find a workaround because I already have implemented socialite and what I want I can get with a curl get request but it seems like I can't get an access token so I might as well just go with the SDK. Is it a good idea to use both socialite and the Facebook SDK just to retrieve information?

Comment: Socialite is only really used for social authentication i.e. logging in with a social provider. If you want anything further you should use the SDK. If you don't need social authentication, then you can take Socialite out of the equation. It's pretty easy to get an access token for what you want just using the SDK. The scopes that Socialite requests from Facebook may not be enough for your needs either.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have followed the previous answer to fix the reference to `$access_token` you can do the following steps with the facebook SDK to retrieve a long lived token from Facebook so you can make many calls to the API. The default auth token will work for 2 hours after which you will need to re-initiate the oAuth flow to get a new token. A long lived token gets you 2 months of access before having to do the oAuth again. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

```
$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook();
$client = $facebook->getOAuth2Client();
$twoMonthToken = $client->getLongLivedAccessToken($twoHourToken);
```

Update the user with the `$twoMonthToken`

Answer (score 0):

`$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($access_token);`

You can simply pass your access_token like above that will return user info.